# Drawing outside canvas on android drawable

Tags: android, canvas, android-drawable

I am trying to draw shadow on my drawable, but the shadow gets cropped, since the rectangle I am drawing is the size of `canvas.getClipBounds()`.

In order to draw the shadow I set the hardware acceleration on the view

```
view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

And I also set the Shadow Layer in my Custom Drawable

```
bgPaint.setShadowLayer(radius, 0, 0, Color.Black);
```

When I draw a small rectangle the shadow is rendered. So, I know my original problem is about the shadowing being discarded for being outside of the canvas.

I tried some approaches, such as:

[Setting the `Drawable`'s bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11572861/2313889),

[Increasing the `canvas`' bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15506277/2313889),

[Disable `clipChildren` on the parent `view`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20118581/2313889),

[Overriding `Drawable.getPadding()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26063830/2313889)

But none of them helped me.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: Sorry, I can't remember properly, but I don't think so. I think I had to find a different way to get the result I wanted.